# Can I use an Azure Dev Ops build definition both for a Release Management pipeline and a pull request but with the latter not triggering the pipeline

Tags: git, build, azure-devops, release-management, pull-request

In short; we want to use a build definition to both generate artifacts for  Release Management and checking Pull Requests, but not allow the latter to trigger a new release.

We have CI build definition on our Git Repo feeding artifacts into a Release Management Pipeline. Like many teams we also have Pull Requests set up to protect our git master. We'd like to reuse our CI build to validate Pull Requests before they are merged in but doing so automatically triggers our release pipeline (bypassing the merge to master).

We've been working round this so far by duplicating builds but that feels clunky. Looking through the documentation there isn't an obvious way to filter a Release Trigger, or skip the publishing step in the build. I feel there must be away of preventing the trigger without duplicating the build but I can't see it!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Azure Dev Ops now has a way of achieving this behaviour. You can modify the Continuous Deployment trigger for a Release definition. The two applicable options are:

- Disable the (handily titled) Pull Request trigger
- Add a branch filter i.e. include only master

[image: Screenshot of Continuous deployment trigger setup dialog]

Note another answer suggested making the artifact upload conditional, however we still needed the artifact for other reasons.

Comment: If you are wanting the artifact from the PR this is a simple way of letting the CI/Gate produce the same artifact in every scenario but limiting the release pipeline to only "release candidate" artifacts. Thanks for posting your answer and defining the need for the artifact in both PR and CI situations.

Comment: Well it was also in the first line of the question, but I'll take it as feedback that I might need to structure my questions more clearly!

Comment: You are right, I missed that as a requisite. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of box feature to achieve this for now, there is already a similar feature request submitted on VSTS User Voice and you can vote it: [Trigger release definition only for specific branches](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/13413054-trigger-release-definition-only-for-specific-branc).

The alternative way to achieve to this would updating your release definition to configure it to be triggered by "Manual", and then add a PowerShell script task in your build definition to check the source refs of current build and then trigger the release via [VSTS Rest API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/rm/releases#create-a-release).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is too old a question for this answer to be valid, but if you're now using Azure DevOps (formerly VSTS) you can accomplish this by using the [**Control Options: Custom Conditions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=designer) for the task of the CI build that publishes the artifacts.

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Personally, we have decided to go the route of having a separate build definition for the **Gate** vs **CI** where the gate is a bare bones version of the CI build to restore, build, test, pack (if necessary). We want the gates to be quick, so they don't even bother with publishing artifacts that might find their way into a release pipeline. We mitigate the "Clunky-ness" of this solution by separating them into a gate folder within their topic.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, this wouldn't have worked for us because we still needed to be able to view the artifact post build. However it motivated me to post the solution we now use, that is to use the continuous build trigger options. Re your comment: We do use conditionals on other tasks to speed up the PR build, it is a trade off, but DRY was the tipping point for us.

Answer (score -1):

The ability to trigger releases based on the build's refspec isn't a capability at present.

Comment: I understand that there isn't an official trigger property. I was looking for workarounds perhaps using scripting or other features I might not have noticed.

Answer (score -1):

In Azure DevOps I wasn't able to fully stop the releases from triggering but I was able to sort circuit them getting the branch that triggered the release and then using a custom condition on my release tasks, skip them if the triggering branch was `merge`

### PowerShell task

Below is the PowerShell I'm currently using in the very first task

```
# Use the triggering artifact alias and constructing the name of the variable that will ultimately get us the source branch that triggered the release
$SrcBranchName = "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_$(('$(RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS)' -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+','_').ToUpper())_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"

# Get the environment variable that holds the name of the source branch
$SrcBranchName = Get-Item  env:$SrcBranchName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
Write-Host "SrcBranchName: $SrcBranchName"

if ($SrcBranchName -eq "merge") {
    Write-Host "Release caused by a PR - no further steps will run."
}

# Set an environment variable with the source branch name for use in a Custom Conditions Control
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TriggeringArtifactSourceBranchName;]$SrcBranchName"
```

### Custom Condition

Then for my custom conditions in each task, I use the following which skips the task if the `TriggeringArtifactSourceBranchName` is set to `merge`.

```
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['TriggeringArtifactSourceBranchName'], 'merge'))
```

Comment: There is a built in filter on CD triggers in ADO now, so you shouldn't need to do that.

Comment: @Lex Yeah but that won't work for all scenarios such as building from various different feature branches.  You can't expect to change the exclusion filter every time a Pull Request build kicks off when you start a merge.  Additionally, you can't just set it to Master because you may want to do a manual build of a feature branch.  Just saying, there are use cases (that we hit at least) where something more dynamic was necessary.

Comment: That sounds a bit like an answer to another question. Even so, you should be able to use the inclusive filter and then simply create a manual release with a hand picked artifact to cover your dynamic scenario.